# sox command is automatically adding delay in the begining of mp3

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, sox, delay

I have a few video files which have "humm" sound in the audio. So, I created the following script for batch processing. **I am using `ffmpeg`, to extract audio to .mp3, and [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) to denoise,** which will output noise free mp3 file.

[image]

```bsh
mkdir -p ./tmp;
for f in *.mp4;
do
    title=${f%.mp4};
    echo "Working on $f";
    mv ./"$f" ./tmp/ && ffmpeg -i ./tmp/"$f" -f mp3 -ab 128000 -vn ./tmp/"$title"_noise.mp3;

    echo "Sox process started...";
    sox -v 0.80 ./tmp/"$title"_noise.mp3 ./tmp/"$title"_128.mp3 noisered ./noise_profile 0.20 && sox ./tmp/"$title"_128.$mp3 -C 96 ./$title.mp3;

    echo "Removing Audio from video file...";
    ffmpeg -loglevel warning -stats -y -i ./tmp/"$f" -c copy -an ./"$f";
done
```

But the problem is, I observed that there is `00:00:00.050s` (HH:MM:SS.ms - Checked with Audacity) of delay added to the final mp3 file. I believe **Sox** is adding this delay.

1. **How can I solve this? Or, how can I remove/trim `00.050` seconds from the
   beginning and add `00.050` seconds of silence at the end of the
   audio track?** OR
2. **Is there any other better way to finish my task?**

NOTE: I am trying to work with `.wav` instead of `.mp3` after reading below reply, if it works I will update here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Answers for my own questions. There are 2 ways to solve this. Answer for my first question is...

> *1. How can I solve this? Or, how can I remove/trim `00.050` seconds from the beginning and add `00.050` seconds of silence at the end of the audio track?*

**Answer 1:** This might be destructive as I am converting mp3 multiple times. Still if someone wants to know. Use below command to `trim` the beginning and use `pad` to add silence at the end.

```bsh
sox Speech_01.mp3 Speech_01_Corrected.mp3 trim 0.049 pad 0 0.050
```

`trim 0.049` will remove 049ms of silence from the beginning. `pad 0 0.050` will add 050ms of silence at the end.

---

### **Answer 2: This is what solved my problem. I followed [instructions from this page](http://www.zoharbabin.com/how-to-do-noise-reduction-using-ffmpeg-and-sox/), and pieced together a batch script.**

> *2. Is there any other better way to finish my task?*

As **`@Artem S. Tashkinov`** pointed out, **LAME** adds delay because of sample differences between `.wav` and `.mp3` formats. *(That is what I understood)*. So, I used only `.wav` [as mentioned in this page](http://www.zoharbabin.com/how-to-do-noise-reduction-using-ffmpeg-and-sox/).

**NOTE:** Below **`sox`** command was deleting a small part from the end of the audio file, for some unknown reason. So, I had to use `pad` to add some silence at the end of the audio, and avoid loosing any part of the audio accidentally. Through trial and error I came to know that `0.010ms` is enough for my case.

```bsh
# You can observe pad here, which is adding silence at the end.
sox ./tmp/"$title"_noisy.wav ./tmp/"$title"_noisy_s.wav pad 0 0.010

# Below command will delete small part from the end of output wav file,
# Hence the above command.
sox -v 0.80 ./tmp/"$title"_noisy_s.wav ./"$title".wav noisered ./allnoise_profile 0.30
```

### Collecting noises to generate a `noise profile.`

In my case, there were different variations of "hmm" noise in my files. As a result selecting just one noise sample, for all files, was not working for me. Hence I copied variations which were escaping and created one `.wav` file (`allnoise_samples.wav`), using [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/). **Note:** Having silence between variations didn't work for me. So, samples are continuous.

[image]

```bsh
# Use below command to generate a noise sample file.
sox ./allnoise_samples.wav -n noiseprof ./allnoise_profile
```

### Here is the final script for batch processing.

Working with `.wav` files is heavy on storage. So, I am deleting them as soon as their purpose is fulfilled.

```bsh
mkdir -p ./tmp;
for f in *.mp4;
do
    title=${f%.mp4};
    echo -e "\n\n$f - Splitting Audio and video files...";
    mv ./"$f" ./tmp/"$title"_O.mp4 && ffmpeg -i ./tmp/"$title"_O.mp4 -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 128k -vn ./tmp/"$title"_noisy.wav;
    ffmpeg -i ./tmp/"$title"_O.mp4 -c copy -an ./"$title"_v.mp4;

    echo "Adding Silence at the end...";
    sox ./tmp/"$title"_noisy.wav ./tmp/"$title"_noisy_s.wav pad 0 0.010 && rm -rf ./tmp/"$title"_noisy.wav;

    echo "Sox process started...";
    sox -v 0.80 ./tmp/"$title"_noisy_s.wav ./"$title".wav noisered ./allnoise_profile 0.30 && rm -rf ./tmp/"$title"_noisy_s.wav;

    echo -e "Sox finished... \nMerging Audio and video files...";
    ffmpeg -loglevel warning -stats -y -i ./"$title"_v.mp4 -i ./"$title".wav -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 96k ./"$f";
    rm -rf ./"$title"_v.mp4 ./"$title".wav;
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be down to the MP3 (MPEG-1 Audio Layer III) standard:

https://lame.sourceforge.io/tech-FAQ.txt

Read the section: "Why does LAME add silence to the beginning each song?"

Comment: Thank you. I understood what happend here. I am trying to work with `.wav` instead of `.mp3` after reading your reply, if it works I will update here.